# dynamic variable using name reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create generic functionality for my extension of react-table where i can pass custom components with custom properties to it.

I have JSON that have structure like this:

```
[
  {
      "Header": "stg",
      "accessor": "accessor",
      "customComponent": "customComponent",
      "props": {  "functions": 
                    ["functionInProp"],
                  "data":
                    ["prop"]
      }
  }
]
```

Logic behind this should be:

```
 this.customCell = (cell, customComponent, customProps) => {
            // create props to pass to customComponent
            const propsToPass = {};
            if (customProps && customProps.functions) {
                customProps.functions.forEach(fnc => { propsToPass[fnc] = this[fnc]; });
            }
            if (customProps && customProps.data) {
                customProps.data.forEach(data => { propsToPass[data] = data; });
            }
            /* eslint-disable import/no-dynamic-require */
            const ComponentToRender = require(`${EXTENSIONS_PATH}${customComponent}`).default;
            /* eslint-enable import/no-dynamic-require */
            return <ComponentToRender cell={cell} {...propsToPass} />;
        };
```

where **customComponent** and **customProps** are from JSON. Component is loaded correctly. function is passed within props ok - function in parent component is defined in upper scope like :

```
this.functionInProp = () => {}
```

But i dont know how to pass value from variable somewhere named as "prop" within props. This line:

```
if (customProps && customProps.data) {
            customProps.data.forEach(data => { propsToPass[data] = data; });
        }
```

I just need to pass 'data' as "name reference" of variable, not its value.

Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: hmm, have you tried to use `propsToPass['data'] = data;` ?

Comment: @MauricioSipmann your suggestion would create prop named data with value "prop". and in result i need to pass property prop with value of variable prop in code... ahh... hope you understand